# Visual studio 2022 + M1 Android Emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hi has anyone managed to get Android Emulator working on an M1 Mac with Visual Studio? I'm struggling to get it running.

In Visual Studio, Android Device Manager is showing one device

- Android 10.0 - API 29
- arm64-v8a
- 1 GB memory
- 1080 x 1920 resolution
- Base device is Pixel 2 (+ store)

When I select it and press run, I just get a message "The emulator exited unexpectedly, please check the emulator settings".

Not sure what settings need to be changed or corrected though.

**Update**
Running on:

- Visual Studio 2022 for Mac Version 17.3.8 (build 5)
- Xamarin Android 13.0.0.0

Comment: Yep, works fine. Make sure you've updated the Android Emulator in the SDK manager. Otherwise it should just work.

Comment: Did you try to create a new simulator and run it?

Comment: Hi yep just updated and created a new one, getting this error: Device error: PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.

Comment: Did you install the SDK of the android version which you choosed to create a emulator?